# Mesos Marathon deploy was failed when added parameters in Json file

Tags: mesos, marathon

I was trying to deploy ngnix docker container by mesos Marathon, I would like to set some environment variables in the container, so I added parameter section in the Json file, but after I added the parameter section, it was failed. My Json file as following:

```
{
  "container":{
    "type":"DOCKER",
    "docker":{
      "image":"nginx",
      "network":"BRIDGE",
      "portMappings":[{"containerPort":80,"hostPort":0,"servicePort":80,"protocol":"tcp"}],
      "parameters": [
                { "key": "myhostname", "value": "a.corp.org" }
            ]
    }
  },
  "id":"nginx7",
  "instances":1,
  "cpus":0.25,
  "mem":256,
  "uris":[]
}
```

my launch script was: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 10.3.11.11:8080/v2/apps -d@"$@"`

The command I ran was: `./launch.sh nginx.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the wrong parameter key `myhostname`, if you want to setup `hostname` for you container, it should be:

```
"parameters": [
            { "key": "hostname", "value": "a.corp.org" }
        ]
```

if you want to pass environment variable, it should be:

```
"parameters": [
            { "key": "env", "value": "myhostname=a.corp.org" }
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you, where I can find the documents about all of parameters keys please.

Comment: The value of `key` is actually option name of `docker run`, so using `"parameters": [
            { "key": "hostname", "value": "a.corp.org" }
        ]` means it will run docker container like `docker run --hostname a.corp.org ...`. You could have a look at `docker help run` or refer to their official docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/